# piecewise construction of a map with initializer list

Tags: c++, c++17

trying to piecewise construct a map(in a map of maps) with initializer list, getting syntax error:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, int>> map;
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(1),
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::initializer_list<std::pair<int, int>>{{1,1}}));
```

try out here: https://onlinegdb.com/S1tzFQkDv

Comment: Please add the complete compilation error(s) to your question. Makes it easier for people to figure out what's going on whiteout relying on external tools to help you out here :)

Comment: @JoelBodenmann in a typical c++ fashion this produces 2+ pages of error messages, posting that error here is no big deal but severely reduces the readability of the question. i find external tool is less of an evil in this case.

Comment: @hmad Joel is right, it's customary to add the full error to the question. It will be displayed in a scrollable box, so it being long doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key type in `initializer_list` needs to be `const`:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::unordered_map<int, int>> map;
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(1),
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const int, int>>{{1,1}}));
```